# Override res.end with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I need to override method res.end with next signature:

```
res.end = (data: any, encoding: string)
```

But TS returns next error:

```
Type '(data: any, encoding: string) => void' is not assignable to type '{ 
(cb?: (() => void) | undefined): void; 
(chunk: any, cb?: (() => void) | undefined): void; 
(chunk: any, encoding: string, cb?: (() => void) | undefined): void; 
}'.ts(2322)
```

I had tried to pass empty callback, but it have not helped:

```
res.end = (data: any, encoding: string, callback: `() =>void`): void
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your function type to `any`, this mean it can convert (or assign) to any type.

Try this

```
res.end = ((data: any, encoding: string): void => { }) as any;
```

Update

You can make a type what extends `express.Response`, it overrides `end` method (the method of `NodeJS.WritableStream`).

```
import { Request, Response, Handler } from 'express';

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

interface MyResponse extends Omit<Response, "end"> {
  end: (data: any, encoding: string) => void;
}

const handler: Handler = (req: Request, res: MyResponse) => {
  res.end = (data: any, encoding: string) => {

  }
};
```

Comment: This hides the important need to check at runtime which argument list is present.

Comment: The approach of creating `MyResponse` will work reliably only if whatever calls `handler` knows about the new signature for `end`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem

Your initial signature does not pass the compiler check, [because the `end` function](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/21e1162029bd6b9f94e8b0843c975aff40fefcba/types/node/v13/stream.d.ts#L156-L158), which `ServerResponse` inherits from `stream.Writable`, has the following overload:

```
end(cb?: () => void): void;
end(chunk: any, cb?: () => void): void;
end(chunk: any, encoding: string, cb?: () => void): void;
```

Since the `end` function has that overload, the compiler is warning you that, at runtime, you need to check which of the overloads is in use.

#### Solution

Here is a signature that is type safe. It checks which of the three arguments is the callback and then acts accordingly.

```
import { Response } from 'express';

const handler = (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  res.end = (arg1: Function | any, arg2?: Function | string, arg3?: Function) => {

    if (typeof arg1 === 'function') {
      // end(cb?: () => void): void;
    }

    if (typeof arg2 === 'function') {
      // end(chunk: any, cb?: () => void): void;
    }

    if (typeof arg3 === 'function') {
      // end(chunk: any, encoding: string, cb?: () => void): void;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Actually, you should use BufferEncoding for the arg2.
res.end = (arg1: Function | any, arg2?: Function | BufferEncoding, arg3?: Function) => { .... } ... Thx for the answer, it helped me a lot.

Comment: @M'sieurToph' Thank you for the feedback. Can you share a link with me, because my sources show that the overload for end uses `string` not `BufferEncoding`. I have added a link to the relevant types to my answer.

Comment: I have no source. My IDE told me it was waiting for BufferEncoding ;) ... But string also worked. Found a link to the type description : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botframework-streaming/bufferencoding?view=botbuilder-ts-latest ... but you are right, I found no relevant source for usage in express ... this is crazy IDE told me that .